# Visual Studio 2015 Issues with an attached console I/O

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

I recently upgraded the solution of an older project to use visual studio 2015. The application runs an opengl application. The application allocates a separate console for output. I use the console to output relevant debug information from within my opengl application.

I have fully upgraded my project and it works correctly. My problem is that when upgrading my project to use the Visual Studio 2015 (v140) toolset from the Visual Studio 2013 (v120) toolset, the console does not display any information when I use any console output functions (stdio.h or iostream). This makes debugging a bit more of a pain.

To be clear I can swap my project back to use the Visual Studio 2013 (v120) toolset and the console will display information when I output to console.

Does any one have any insight into a reason why the newer toolset prevents me from seeing information in my console window? Am I meant to set up a console differently?

---

Link with good clear simple example of console output redirection. (I'd give more examples but I'm link limited) 
http://asawicki.info/news_1326_redirecting_standard_io_to_windows_console.html

example of my console output creation:

```
AllocConsole();
long lStdHandle = (long)GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
int hConHandle = _open_osfhandle(lStdHandle, _O_TEXT);
FILE *fp = _fdopen(hConHandle, "w");
*stdout = *fp;
setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This:

```
*stdout = *fp;
```

is not valid.  `FILE` is an opaque type.  You are only allowed to manipulate a `FILE` via the stdio library functions (`fopen`, `freopen`, `fread`, etc.).

If you want to reopen one of the standard streams to refer to the console, one supported way to do that would be:

```
freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
```

Comment: Thank you for providing a solution to my problem. 

One very minor issue is I have to 

    #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 

because it is unsafe. Why would I be warned about it being unsafe if it is the standard correct way of redirecting the stream.

Comment: A decade ago, some group at Microsoft decided that a bunch of functions were "insecure" and should be deprecated.  They "deprecated" some truly dangerous things (like gets) but they were a bit... overzealous.  Disabling the deprecation warning is fine.  Alternatively, consider `freopen_s`.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis is the "CONOUT$" token documented?   Wouldn't the official way be with _dup2?  (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8syseb29.aspx)

Comment: @OfekShilon `CONOUT$` is documented; see the ["Console Handles"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682075.aspx) page.  `_dup2` would also work.

Answer (score 0):

Check what is in Yours Debug->Options and Settings->Debugging->Output Window in VS.

For me works well if in first label everything is on and second label off (error in data binding).

Hope is going to work.

Comment: Everything in my Debug->Options-> Debugging -> Output window is as you described. All the general output settings are enabled, while all the WPF Trace settings are disabled.


Only exceptions are Databinding set to Warning and Natvis Diagnostic messages off.  
 

  Did you test it with the Visual Studio 2015 (v140) toolset?